# CSS to change Before/After of an Element

Tags: html, css, image, label

I have the following item that is dynamically generated content. I do not have the ability to directly edit the code so I need to find a way to use CSS to make the necessary changes.

In the below image, how can I replace (with CSS) "Description" with an image instead?

[image]

Edit: 
I've already tried the following but no changes take affect.

```
#input_93_0 label {
    content: url(image.jpg);
}
```

```
#label_input_93_0::after {
    content: url(image.jpg);
}
```

```
#input_93_0::after {
  content: "TEST: "; !important
}
```

Other ideas?

Comment: @Paulie_D, my apologies for not including what I had already attempted in my initial post. I've updated my post with a couple attempts I made at achieving this.

Answer (score 0):

Your attempts are trying to target the `::after` pseudo-element.

However, it's clear from the screenshot that this should, in fact, be the `::before` pseudo-element.

So try...

```
#input_93_0::before{
  content: url(your-image-path); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but you suggestion still results in no changes to the output.

Comment: Well unless you can demonstrate the problem there is not much more we can do. This **should** work unless there is a rule with higher specificity.